# special character is not coming in alert box as it it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one code

```
<input type="button" id="btnGetText" value="Get Text"/>
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>First Line&alpha; and text.</p>
    <p>Second Line&nbsp;<b>Bolded</b></p>
</div>
```

If I am alerting the html of #myDiv `&nbsp;` is coming in alert but `&alpha` not coming.
If I am alerting `&alpha` its giving `α`

here is the fiddle attached

http://jsfiddle.net/getyoursuresh/hv2ed/

Comment: you probably should not alert any html, your fiddle comes up as plain text in chhrome 35/windows 7. Except for the alpha character. They are probably not allowed/not supported.

Comment: What do you want it to do? If you don't want the tags and entities showing as they are you should use `.text()`

Comment: i want exact html only..this is somthing my requirement all about

Answer (score 3):

You are not alerting the original HTML. You are alerting a serialization of the DOM to HTML.

`&alpha;` and `α` are equivalent in HTML, so either are perfectly valid when designing a serialization algorithm. HTML 5 [describes the algorithm browsers are supposed to use](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#serializing-html-fragments).

As described in the section starting "Escaping a string", non-breaking spaces should be serialized to character references while alphas are not.

If you want to work with your original HTML then you'll need to use XMLHttpRequest to refetch the original document from the server and then parse the raw text of the response yourself.

Comment: then why &nbsp; is coming in alert ??

Comment: @SachinRawal — `&nbsp;` and a literal non-breaking space character are also equivalent so the browser can use either when serializing to HTML. If I were to speculate, I'd say it was because an alpha character is obviously an alpha character while a non-breaking space is hard to tell apart from a regular space, so the person who wrote the serialization engine decided to use `&nbsp;` to make it obvious what it was.

Comment: Serialization is described as representing NO-BREAK SPACE as `&nbsp;`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#serializing-html-fragments

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela — Thanks. I've integrated that into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:

Alpha character can be used directly in html although it has an html encoding, unlike the unbreakable space which has to remain in html encoding even after processing it because that character only exists in html encoding.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The OP is trying to get the original HTML source. `text()` will get the results of parsing the HTML and converting it to text and will definitely replace all character references with regular characters. This basically does the opposite of what is being asked for.

Comment: jQuery's HTML function just accesses `innerHTML`, the character is coming from the browser's native code, not jQuery.

Comment: No character "only exists in html encoding". Character references just describe unicode code points. [Here are the details for a non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm).

Comment: huh I didn't know nbsp has a unicode! thanks for the info .. but strangely why didn't it turn into the text version like the alpha character since it has a unicode?

Comment: See the comments attached to my answer.